# Problema com float

Tags: html, css

Não estou conseguindo alinhar dois elementos lado a lado corretamente.

O *container* destas duas `div`'s fica como se tivesse com `height: 0;` ou `initial`, apenas reconhecendo a altura do elemento sem o `float: left;`, que neste caso são os links de navegação.

Mas eu queria que o *container* respondesse também à altura do elemento `<div id="logo">`, pois ele agora parece estar a comportar-se como um elemento com `position:absolute;` que independentemente da sua altura, o `height` do *container* não se expande como deveria acontecer se este elemento não tivesse qualquer `float` ou `position:absolute;`.

[image: ERRADO]

[image: CERTO]

A primeira imagem é como ele está atualmente. A segunda, é como deveria de ficar.

```
<header>
<div id="top-bar">
    <div id="logo"></div>
    <nav id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sobre</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Trabalhos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contato</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
</header>
```

CSS

```
a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #4B4B4B;
}

div#top-bar {

background-color: #f14949;
padding: 25px 80px 25px 80px;
}

div#logo {
vertical-align: middle;
float: left;
width: 86px;
height: 51px;
background-color: #4B4B4B;
border-radius: 6px;
}
nav#menu {

text-align: right;
}
nav#menu ul {
list-style: none;
}

nav#menu li {
display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Não percebo qual é o problema. Podes explicar o que querias que fosse o resultado?

Comment: Na verdade eu não percebi que o problema não apareceu aqui no site, porém no navegador mostra claramente.

A div não considera a altura da "Logo" apenas da lista (menu)

Comment: Boa tarde Steve, não é que aqui na pergunta não funciona, é porque você não colocou todo o css, pode ser qualquer coisa que esteja causando o problema, não vai adiantar só por uma imagem mostrando o problema, você tem que criar um exemplo do tal problema que possa ser reproduzido, recomendo que siga atentamente estas dicas: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - entenda isto como uma critica construtiva :)

Answer (score 2):

Para evitar este e outro tipo de problemas com `float`, certifica-te sempre de utilizar um `clear:both;` sempre que acabares de flutuar elementos.

Para isso podes criar uma `class` especifica para fazer essa "limpeza" atribuindo-lhe a propriedade `clear` do CSS, como por exemplo:

```
<header>
    <div id="top-bar">
        <div id="logo"></div>
        <nav id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sobre</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Trabalhos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contato</a></li>
        </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="clear"></div> <!-- Este é o elemento criado, para 'limpeza' dos floats -->
    </div>
</header>
```

Depois no CSS basta criares uma class `.clear` e atribuir-lhe a propriedade `clear`:

```
.clear{clear:both;}
```

> A propriedade `clear:both;` vai evitar com que novos elementos adicionados após estes elementos flutuados, não sejam afectados também por esta propriedade. Especificando e adicionando este elemento, estamos a dizer que a partir do `<div class="clear"></div>`, já não queremos que nada fique flutuado.
>
> Podes ler mais sobre a propriedade `clear`, aqui neste link - [CSS clear Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp)

Comment: Cara muito obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado!

Comment: contente por ter ajudado @SteveAlisson :) Se tiveres algum tempo disponível considera marcar a minha resposta como correta, que também poderá ajudar outras pessoas que possam vir a ter o mesmo problema, perceber que esta resposta te ajudou a resolver o problema.